# Steal from the rich and give to the poor

Tags: single-word-requests, adjectives

I'm trying to remember a single term that's equivalent to someone who steals from the rich to give to the poor. It's not "altruistic," it's something more specific.

Comment: Wealth redistribution?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no simple adjective with this meaning.  "Robin Hood" carries the specific meaning, however, and it can be used (as can many nouns) to modify another noun, as in "the senator's Robin Hood tendencies".

Comment: @HotLicks You're right. How about _robinhood-like_ as the adjective?

Answer (score 5):

The Oxford American English Dictionary says ["Robin Hood"](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/robin-hood) is the term that you're looking for, naturally.

> *(noun)* a person who takes or steals money from rich people and gives it to poor people
>
> *"He was seen as an educational Robin Hood with his proposal to take federal money out of the hands of schools and place it in the hands of students."*

There are many snarky terms - "Liberal", "Socialist", "Democrat", etc., but they don't actually mean this.

Comment: I just noticed that the question is tagged "adjectives". I think you should add information to this answer about if "Robin Hood" can be used as an adjective. To me, it seems to be a noun only.

Comment: @sumelic How about _robinhood-like_ as the adjective?

Answer (score -1):

How about **benevolent**?

OD:

> [**benevolent**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/benevolent):
>   well meaning and kindly; (of an organization) serving a charitable
>   rather than a profit-making purpose

One could consider Robin Hood and his band of merry men a **benevolent** organization, one organized around the purpose of stealing from the rich and giving to the poor, thereby undermining the prevailing moral order.

Comment: Benevolent has a lot of meanings besides that.

Comment: @DJClayworth I know, but it was the best word I could find, excepting the noun *Robin Hood*.  I think it works, at least from the point of view of the downtrodden.